# XAMPP Error on MySQL: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. No similar problem on the web

Tags: mysql, xampp

I've been trying to reinstalling the Xampp (I tried to back up with copying the folder as well). But the problem still appears. It says `Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.`

Here's the log:

```
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.13 started; log sequence number 3854135; transaction id 5114
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200824 19:45:30
2020-08-24 19:45:30 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I have no clue about what to do as I tried to search the problem on the web but I can't find the exact problem like this.

I appreciate all the attempts to solve my problem later.

Edit: I opened the Event Viewer and found this error such as

```
Initialized Master_info from 'master-2020@002d06@002d25@002020@003a24@003a52@002016@0020@005bnote@005d@0020master@0020@00272020@002d06@002d25@002020@003a08@003a52@00200@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020some@0020master_info@0020entries@0020failed@000d@0027@003a@0020slave@0020i@002fo@0020thread@0020exiting@002c@0020read@0020up@0020to@0020log@0020@0027first@00.info' failed
```

and also this error

```
Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593 
Failed to initialize multi master structures
```

Comment: None of the log entries are errors, so we cannot tell based on those what could have gone wrong. There can be hundreds of diffrent causes for mysql to crash. You need to find a proper error log that gives you an indication of the underlying issue.

Comment: I found some errors when I opened Event Viewers. I just edited the question, hope that's help

Answer (score 0):

Found [this forum post](https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=265827&sid=f5dfeb95d530e83c90681907840b4082) with very similar log errors that you are getting, the solution they gave is to delete `aria_log.00000001` under `C:\xampp\mysql\data`, although don't outright delete it, I'd recommend renaming it to `aria_log.00000001.bak` in case it doesn't fix your problem, then you can just restore it.